# How to merge two rows so 2 years of data is represtented in one row

Tags: r

[This is a cutout of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxzzl.png)
I have a dataframe where i have two different variables that is found one year apart from each other. I would like to combine for exampel 2007 and 2008 to make one row with both variable and name it Denmark2007/8.
I have about 300 rows to do this with, and cannot find a command that will do this, and typing it mannually is not in the question

I have looked at everything from merge() and colsums, and i am lost

Comment: Please post `dataframe[3757:3762, ]` as code/text, ideally with `dput`, e.g. `dput(dataframe[3757:3762, ])`.

Answer (score 2):

While one can debate whether a wide format data frame will be easiest to use in subsequent analysis steps, the tricky part of this request is that the names of countries may include multiple words. This means that a simpler solution like `tidyr::separate()` with `sep = " "` isn't feasible.

Here is a solution that uses length of each Country to extract the last 4 characters into a `Year` column, and everything before the final space as Country.

For the purposes of this example, `v1` represents the odd year data, and `v2` represents the even year data.

### Refactored Solution

After coding the tidyverse friendly answer (see below), I realized I could simplify the original solution by starting with the long form tidy data, splitting it into even and odd years, renaming columns and then merging by year.

First, we create data based on the graphic in the original post, and add a couple of rows for a country whose name includes multiple words.

```
textData <- "v1,Country,v2
0.93181,Denmark 2007,NA
NA,Denmark 2008,5.519108
0.64285,Denmark 2009,NA
NA,Denmark 2010,4.93885
.55260,Denmark 2011,NA
NA,Denmark 2012,5.101908
0.13187,United Kingdom 2007,NA
NA,United Kingdom 2008,3.18781"

df <- read.csv(text = textData)
```

After reading the data into a data frame, we extract the last 4 characters from the `Country` column to create `Year`, merge `v1` and `v2` into a single column, add a `yearType` column, and use it to split the data into even and odd years.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(countryLength = str_length(Country),
            countryName = substr(Country,1,countryLength - 5),
            Year = as.numeric(substr(Country,countryLength - 4,countryLength)),
            value = if_else(!is.na(v1),v1,v2),
            yearType = if_else(Year %% 2 == 0,"Even","Odd")) %>%
     select(!c(Country,countryLength,v1,v2)) %>%
     rename(Country = countryName) %>%
     split(.$yearType) -> dataList
```

Having split the data into two data frames, we now rename columns in the even year data frame, subtract 1 from `Year` to merge with the odd numbered year data, join with the odd numbered year data, rename a few columns and add a column for the even numbered years.

```
dataList$Even %>%
     rename(EvenYearValue = value) %>%
     mutate(Year = Year - 1) %>% 
     select(-yearType) %>% 
     full_join(dataList$Odd,by = c("Country","Year")) %>%
     rename(OddYearValue = value,
            OddYear = Year) %>%
     mutate(EvenYear = OddYear + 1) %>% select(-yearType)
```

...and the output:

```
         Country OddYear EvenYearValue OddYearValue EvenYear
1        Denmark    2007      5.519108      0.93181     2008
2        Denmark    2009      4.938850      0.64285     2010
3        Denmark    2011      5.101908      0.55260     2012
4 United Kingdom    2007      3.187810      0.13187     2008
>
```

If it is absolutely required to append the start and end years to the `Country` column, that can be accomplished as follows.

```
dataList$Even %>%
     rename(EvenYearValue = value) %>%
     mutate(Year = Year - 1) %>% 
     select(-yearType) %>% 
     full_join(dataList$Odd,by = c("Country","Year")) %>%
     rename(OddYearValue = value,
            OddYear = Year) %>%
     mutate(EvenYear = OddYear + 1) %>% select(-yearType) %>%
     # modify the Country name to include years
     mutate(Country = paste(Country,OddYear,"-",EvenYear))
```

...and the output:

```
                     Country OddYear EvenYearValue OddYearValue EvenYear
1        Denmark 2007 - 2008    2007      5.519108      0.93181     2008
2        Denmark 2009 - 2010    2009      4.938850      0.64285     2010
3        Denmark 2011 - 2012    2011      5.101908      0.55260     2012
4 United Kingdom 2007 - 2008    2007      3.187810      0.13187     2008
>
```

### Original Solution

First, we covert the graphic from the question into usable data, and include a couple of rows for a country name that contains multiple words.

```
textData <- "v1,Country,v2
0.93181,Denmark 2007,NA
NA,Denmark 2008,5.519108
0.64285,Denmark 2009,NA
NA,Denmark 2010,4.93885
.55260,Denmark 2011,NA
NA,Denmark 2012,5.101908
0.13187,United Kingdom 2007,NA
NA,United Kingdom 2008,3.18781"

df <- read.csv(text = textData)
```

Next, we load a couple of packages, create a column to count the number of characters in each row of `Country`, and use it to separate `Year` from `countryName`.  We also drop the intermediary columns created during this operation and save the result to `yearlyData`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(countryLength = str_length(Country),
            countryName = substr(Country,1,countryLength - 5),
            Year = as.numeric(substr(Country,countryLength - 4,countryLength))) %>%
     select(!c(Country,countryLength)) %>%
     rename(Country = countryName) -> yearlyData
```

At this point we separate the even years data into another data frame, drop the `v1` variable, and subtract 1 from `Year` so we can merge it with the data for odd numbered years.

```
yearlyData %>%
     filter(Year %% 2 == 0) %>%
     select(-v1) %>% 
     mutate( Year = Year - 1) -> evenYears
```

Next, we read the yearly data, `filter()` out the rows for even numbered years, merge in the `evenYears` data frame via `full_join()`, rename a few columns and generate a new column for the even numbered years.

```
yearlyData %>% 
     filter(Year %% 2 == 1) %>%
     rename(OddYearValue = v1) %>% 
     select(-v2) %>% 
     full_join(.,evenYears,by = c("Year","Country")) %>%
     rename(EvenYearValue = v2,
            OddYear = Year) %>%
     mutate(EvenYear = OddYear + 1)
```

...and the output:

```
  OddYearValue        Country OddYear EvenYearValue EvenYear
1      0.93181        Denmark    2007      5.519108     2008
2      0.64285        Denmark    2009      4.938850     2010
3      0.55260        Denmark    2011      5.101908     2012
4      0.13187 United Kingdom    2007      3.187810     2008
>
```

**NOTE:** that the tidy data specification assets that each column in a data frame should contain one and only one variable, so we did not combine `OddYear`, `EvenYear` and `Country` into a single column as requested in the original post.

### A tidy friendly solution

In the [classic article](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) on this topic, Hadley Wickham defines two forms of tidy data, narrow / long form and wide form.

The following solution creates a tidy data long form data frame, where each row in the resulting table is one value for each combination of `Country` and `Year`.

```
textData <- "v1,Country,v2
0.93181,Denmark 2007,NA
NA,Denmark 2008,5.519108
0.64285,Denmark 2009,NA
NA,Denmark 2010,4.93885
.55260,Denmark 2011,NA
NA,Denmark 2012,5.101908
0.13187,United Kingdom 2007,NA
NA,United Kingdom 2008,3.18781"

df <- read.csv(text = textData)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     mutate(countryLength = str_length(Country),
            countryName = substr(Country,1,countryLength - 5),
            Year = as.numeric(substr(Country,countryLength - 4,countryLength)),
            value = if_else(!is.na(v1),v1,v2)) %>%
     select(!c(Country,countryLength,v1,v2)) %>%
     rename(Country = countryName) -> yearlyData

yearlyData
```

...and the output:

```
> yearlyData
         Country Year    value
1        Denmark 2007 0.931810
2        Denmark 2008 5.519108
3        Denmark 2009 0.642850
4        Denmark 2010 4.938850
5        Denmark 2011 0.552600
6        Denmark 2012 5.101908
7 United Kingdom 2007 0.131870
8 United Kingdom 2008 3.187810
>
```

Ironically, given the input data, it's much easier to create a long form tidy data frame than it is to format the data as requested in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make very specific assumptions about the whole dataset. I hope they apply also to the rest of the table:

1. You always merge *two* rows together (not more than two)
2. The format of the column with Country + year is always the same
3. Older years (e.g. 2007) always have a non-NA value in the first column and an NA in the last column, while the opposite is true for more recent years (e.g. 2008).

If these assumptions hold, I thought to work it out by first creating two tibbles containing the columns for `Country` and `year`, only the non-NA values in `v1` and `v2`, respectively (i.e. dropping all the NAs).

Then you add one year to the tibble containing `v1`, and finally perform an inner join on the year.

To make it more readable, and do not repeat code, I created a function that takes care of the string extraction.

---

```
# Import data and libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df <- tribble(
  ~v1,~Country,~v2,
  #--|--|---
  0.93181,"Denmark 2007",NA,
  NA,"Denmark 2008",5.519108,
  0.64285,"Denmark 2009",NA,
  NA,"Denmark 2010",4.93885,
  0.55260,"Denmark 2011",NA,
  NA,"Denmark 2012",5.101908,
  0.13187,"New Zealand 2007",NA,
  NA,"New Zealand 2008",3.187819
)


# Regular expressions to extract year and country from the Country column
regexp_year <- "[[:digit:]]+"
regexp_country <- "[[:alpha:]\\s]+"


# Function that carries out the string extraction from the `Country` column
do_separate_df <- function(df) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(year = str_extract(Country,regexp_year) %>% as.numeric()) %>%
    mutate(Country = str_extract(Country,regexp_country))
}


# Tibble with non-NA values in v1 (earlier year)
df_v1 <- df %>% 
  select(v1,Country) %>%
  drop_na %>% 
  do_separate_df() 


# Tibble with non-NA values in v2 (later year)
df_v2 <- df %>% 
  select(Country,v2) %>% 
  drop_na %>% 
  do_separate_df()


# Join on df_v1$year + 1 = df_v2$year
df_combined <-inner_join(
  df_v1 %>% mutate(year_to_match = year + 1),
  df_v2, 
  by=c("year_to_match" = "year", "Country")
) %>% 
  mutate(Country = paste(Country, year, year + 1, sep = " ")) %>%
  relocate(Country) %>%
  select(-c(year,year_to_match))
  
df_combined
```

| **Country** | **v1** | **v2** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Denmark 2007 2008 | 0.93181 | 5.519108 |
| Denmark 2009 2010 | 0.64285 | 4.938850 |
| Denmark 2011 2012 | 0.55260 | 5.101908 |
| New Zealand 2007 2008 | 0.13187 | 3.187819 |

Comment: I like this solution. I can’t work on it now, but I thought simple a way to approach this was to fill the first column down and the 3rd column up. Then, paste together a country year variable with a lagged version of itself. Finally group by this combined country year variable and take one row from each group. This might work, but I like the clever approach of merging on year + 1.